# I am trying to upload screenshot taken by selenium webdriver to blob storage as whole of the testing is being done on vsts cloud service

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-blob-storage

I am not able to upload screenshots taken during testing into blob storage.I read the microsoft article but not able to understand.Can you please direct me to correct path or code?The File option in the http request is something that i cant figure out.As i do not have a location on Drive to save image and then from there upload it to storage.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    class ScreenShot
    {
        public static void UploadImage_URL(string ImageName)
        {
            string accountname = "";

            string accesskey = "";

            try
            {

                StorageCredentials creden = new StorageCredentials(accountname, accesskey);

                CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(creden, useHttps: true);

                CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                CloudBlobContainer cont = client.GetContainerReference("validation-results");

                cont.CreateIfNotExists();

                cont.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob

                });

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(file);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                CloudBlockBlob cblob = cont.GetBlockBlobReference(ImageName);
                cblob.UploadFromStream(inputStream);
            }

            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }

        }

        public static void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver)
        {

            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            string Runname = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss");
            String ScreenShotName = Runname + ".Jpg"; 

             UploadImage_URL(ScreenShotName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try saving it as a byte[] ?
Try this:

```
public static void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver)
    {

        Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        var filename = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss")}.jpg";
        Byte[] screen = ss.AsByteArray;


        UploadImage_URL(filename, array);
    }

    public static void UploadImage_URL(string filename, byte[] array)
    {
        string accountname = "";

        string accesskey = "";

        try
        {

            StorageCredentials creden = new StorageCredentials(accountname, accesskey);

            CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(creden, useHttps: true);

            CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer cont = client.GetContainerReference("validation-results");

            cont.CreateIfNotExists();

            cont.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob

            });

            CloudBlockBlob cblob = cont.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
            cblob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(array, 0, array.Lenght);
        }

        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }

    }
```